# After insert data to a partitioned table, why the num_rows is 0 in user_tab_partitions?

Tags: oracle, performance, partitioning

Question 1. Is the data not insert to the specified partition successfully?
As I need to delete the specified partition, so I need make sure the insert into specified partition must successfully although the num_rows is 0 in user_tab_partitions.

Question 2. I have googled some ideas, some say I need to analyze the table.
why need to analyze?

Question 3.
if I analyze the table, will the performance be different compared to not analyzing it?

[image]

```
PARTITION BY RANGE ( CYCLE_MTH ) INTERVAL ( numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH') )
( 
PARTITION per_limra_p004
    VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('01-11-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') ),
PARTITION per_limra_p003
    VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('01-12-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') ),
PARTITION per_limra_p002
    VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('01-01-2016','DD-MM-YYYY') ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NUM_ROWS` shows the number of rows based on last analyze, so you should not rely on it. I suggest to run a count on it, e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM your_table PARTITION FOR (DATE '2016-04-01')
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(ROWNUM)
FROM your_table PARTITION FOR (DATE '2016-04-01')
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

It should be much faster than `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS` (provided you have any index on this table)

Comment: Actually,The data has inserted into the specified partition successfully, right?

Comment: I have add my partitioning SQL to the question body,I have inserted one data for cycle_mth=2015-May-31, and then I used SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM per_limra PARTITION FOR (DATE '2015-06-01'); the result is 1 which is correct. but when I SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM per_limra PARTITION FOR (DATE '2015-05-01'); the result is 1 too, why ?

Comment: We don't have access to your database, nor can we see how your table is defined. I suggest running `SELECT * FROM PER_LIMRA` to see what's actually in the table.

Comment: @BobJarvis . I Have checked the data. result is normal.I can figure it out that why this case happen？

Comment: @Tom: see my answer for the solution to the question raised in your comment above.

Comment: @Wernfried,Sorry for typo

Comment: @Wernfried, Does DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS or analyse table is necessary after I delete one partition (1.9 million data) from the target table (27 partitions ,50 million data)

Comment: It depends on the characteristic of your data and your queries. Typically Oracle determines automatically whether it is needed (any analyze every night) or not.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't constantly update its statistics about tables and partitions, as this would be too heavy. Once you analyze the table, the statistics (e.g., those in `user_tab_partitions`) will be updated. Since Oracle now has different statistics, the optimizer may very well create different execution plans for your queries, and thus affect performance.

Comment: Thanks Mureinik, As I want to add some new partitions, But when I ALTER TABLE tar
  ADD PARTITION tar_001 VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('01-12-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') ); There encountered an error :ADD PARTITION is not permitted on Interval partitioned object. Is there any ways to solve it without changing the 'Interval partitioned' attribute?

Comment: @Tom with interval partitioning, you don't need to add partitions. Just insert your data, and oracle will automatically create the required partition as you do so.

Comment: So,actually we I create the partitioned table, No need to define so many partitions manually, only keep one partition ,right? PARTITION per_limra_p004
    VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('01-11-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') ),

Comment: @Tom yup. Hose are only the initial partitions. If you don't have a special reason to define them preemptively, just don't.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the partition information you've added to your question, the answer is clear. The reason that

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM per_limra PARTITION FOR (DATE '2015-06-01')
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM per_limra PARTITION FOR (DATE '2015-05-01')
```

both return 1 is that they're both looking at the same partition. Your three partitions are

```
PARTITION per_limra_p004
  VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('01-11-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), i.e. less than 01-Nov-2015

PARTITION per_limra_p003
  VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('01-12-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), i.e. less than 01-Dec-2015

PARTITION per_limra_p002
  VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('01-01-2016','DD-MM-YYYY'), i.e. less than 01-Jan-2016
```

The dates in your queries are `DATE '2015-06-01'`, or 01-Jun-2015, and `DATE '2015-05-01'`, or 01-May-2015, both of which fall into the range for partition `per_limra_p004`, which contains data for all dates prior to 01-Nov-2015. Thus, both queries return data from the same partition, which is why they return the same value.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Bob,Very clear,I have a relative question,Please help advise if you could,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51354262/after-drop-the-partition-the-index-became-unusable-what-should-i-do